# Create and execute .bat file in spring web mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, batch-file

I have several questions:

1. How to create and execute **.bat** file in `Spring MVC`?
2. While the execution process show in progress bar

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, what you're asking for has less to do with Spring, and more related to the underlying Java solution.

Creating a batch **.bat** file with Spring is as straight forward as opening a `new FileWriter(new File())` and writing in everything you need, but making sure to append "**.bat**" as the filename's extension. 
As for execution, you can use Spring's [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) on a custom created class of yours, provided that it implements Runnable. If you're looking for a recommendation as to how exactly to **run** the bat, this little snippet will work perfectly:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start batchFile.bat");
```

The idea here is that you can get the Java runtime to execute the Windows command line with those arguments. ("/c" closes cmd on finish).

On the topic of a progress bar, I suspect you will have much difficulty with that, but a solution may lie with having the batch file output progress to System.out(the underlying system resource) and then having your Spring app redirect(?) and read from it.